# Shiny's updateSliderInput output does not seem correct

Tags: r, shiny

The updated scale on a sliderInput looks strange:

```r
library(shiny)

ui = shiny::fluidPage(
    shiny::sidebarLayout(
        shiny::sidebarPanel(
            shiny::sliderInput("n", "n", min = 2, max = 36, value = 9),
            shiny::checkboxInput("auto","Change slider", value = TRUE)
        ),
        shiny::mainPanel(
            shiny::plotOutput("show")
        )
    )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$auto, {
        n = input$n
        if (input$auto) {
            shiny::updateSliderInput(session, "n", min = 2, max = 36, value = n)
        } else {
            shiny::updateSliderInput(session, "n", min = 3, max = 15,  value = max(min(n, 15), 3))
        }
    })
    
    output$show = renderPlot({
        plot(input$n)
    })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When you uncheck the box, the major ticks are 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, with two minor tick marks between two major. How can this be fixed?

Comment: What aspect seems strange to you?

Comment: When you uncheck the box, the major ticks are 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, with two minor tick marks between two major.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider changing to sliderTextInput from shinyWidgets for this level of control
[image: samp]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui = shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::sidebarLayout(
    shiny::sidebarPanel(
      sliderTextInput(inputId = "n", 
                      label = "n", 
                      choices = 2:36, 
                      selected = 9, 
                      grid = TRUE),
      shiny::checkboxInput("auto","Change slider", value = TRUE)
    ),
    shiny::mainPanel(
      shiny::plotOutput("show")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$auto, {
    n = input$n
    if (input$auto) {
      updateSliderTextInput(session, "n", choices = 2:36, selected = n)
    } else {
      updateSliderTextInput(session, "n", choices = 2:15,  selected = max(min(n, 15)))
    }
  })
  
  output$show = renderPlot({
    plot(input$n)
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! I prefer to use 'base' shiny and if needed shinyjs, because it is for a package for which I would like to have minimal dependencies.